# jquery `.ajax` not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am a n00b trying to learn jquery `.ajax` via online tutorials.

I have the following code for the 'client' on my localhost:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $("#submit_btn").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "response.php",
                      dataType: 'json',
                      data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
                }).done(function( msg ) 
                {
                  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                });
            });
        }); 
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

And I have the following code on my 'server' side file called 'response.php':

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST))
{
$answer = $_POST;
echo json_encode($answer);
}  else {
echo json_encode("no good");
}
?>
```

When I click the 'send' button, I get an alert that says "Data Saved: [object Object]".  I'm trying to get the alert to show the data being submitted via `post' using the click event.  I want the alert to show 'name: "John", Location: "Boston"'.

Comment: check your console for any errors, it might be throwing a parse error

Comment: I'm not a php guy, still I have doubts about `json_encode("no good")` giving a json o/p

Comment: is your request giving `no good` as the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"Data Saved: " + msg.name + " " + msg.location`

What you receive is `JSON` object, so printing an object in `javascript` prints `[object Object]`. You should access properties of your object using `.` (dot) operator to get name and location.

Suppose, your response is the following JSON object:

`msg = { name : "John", last_name : "Doe" }`

to access `name` property of your `msg` object you use dot operator:

`console.log(msg.name);`

To make your code generic, you should be able to somehow tell the client whether the request went good or bad. So you could send `status` back like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST))
{
$answer = $_POST;
$answer['status'] = true;
echo json_encode($answer);
}  else {
echo json_encode(array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'no good'));
}
?>
```

on the client you would have to check `status`:

```
function(response) {
  if (response.status) {
    console.log('yep, post was submitted, name is ' + response.name + ', location is ' + response.location);
  }
  else {
    console.log('something went wrong: ' + response.msg);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

And one more thing: once you decided to use `JSON`, don't send `text/plain` back. This is exactly what you doing here:

`echo json_encode("no good");`

this code a produces string `"no good"` which is `text/plain`, but not a valid `JSON` object.

[`Take a look at what JSON is`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Comment: @Nemoden, thanks very much.  I'm confused, however, about the 'function(response)' on the client side.  Does 'response' have to do with the name do the server side file: "response.php"?

Comment: nope, it's just an argument to a callback function. Could be anything.

Comment: @Nemoden, Ok.  Think I'm starting to finally get this.  So, your use of "response" is analogus to my use of "msg" in my original code, yes?  It's just a way to pass the response from the server into the function, yes?  Thanks again for your help.